# best way to execute query in mongodb(3.0 drivers) and nodejs

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb

**db.js**

```
  var mongodb = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
  var settings = require("./settings.js");
  var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
  var db = {
    selectData: function(collection, query, callback, project = false) {
      mongodb.connect(settings.db_url, function(err, client) {
        var database = client.db(settings.db_name);
        if (err) throw err;
        if (project !== false) {
          console.log("Project is not false");
          console.log( project);
          database.collection(collection).find(query, project).toArray(function(err, result) {
            client.close();
            if (err) throw err;
            callback(result);
          });
        } else {
          database.collection(collection).find(query).toArray(function(err, result) {
            client.close();
            if (err) throw err;
            callback(result);
          });
        }
      });
    }
  }


  module.exports = db;
```

**server.js**

here is a simple query with single database call takes few seconds not a big deal but still not good method as per experts.

```
var db = require("db.js");
db.selectData("testCollection",{},function(data){
console.log(data);
});
```

Now here is a multi query nested database calls which takes more time and really bad for performance and speed

```
 var db = require("db.js");
    db.selectData("testCollection", {}, function(data) {
      db.selectData("testCollection", {}, function(data) {
        db.selectData("testCollection", {}, function(data) {
          db.selectData("testCollection", {}, function(data) {
            db.selectData("testCollection", {}, function(data) {
              console.log(data);
            });
          });
        });
      });
    });
```

What i want is open connection once and use db object outside without connecting again and again for each request or nested querys for fast response

i also know that with **mongodb nodejs 2.3 drivers** its possible and i have tested it perfectly working but i am looking for solution how to do same with **mongodb nodejs 3.0 drivers**

in short i am looking for a method where i can connect once and execute querys faster  for chat and real time applications  and performance optimizations

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i found a great working code with nodejs 3.0 Mongodb drivers

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
const url = 'mongodb://Your connection string';
const dbName = 'your database name';



MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client) {
  const db = client.db(dbName);

  app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    db.collection("somedata").find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      res.send(JSON.stringify(result));
    });
  });
  app.listen(3000);
});
```

Instead of connecting again and again for each request connect at once and use it for best way if database connection is lost you can connect again but here you have to use some logic to make live that connection again and app routes too

this works for me i hope it will work for developers looking for answers of this question